# JPA select ignoring OR part

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, select, eclipselink

I have select query:

```
SELECT entity
FROM EnterpriseEventLog entity 
WHERE entity.enterprise.recordId = :recordIdEnterprise     
OR  entity.group.enterprise.recordId = :recordIdEnterprise
```

But part "entity.enterprise.recordId = :recordIdEnterprise" is ignored by JPA, select works like there is no such part. If I delete this "OR  entity.group.enterprise.recordId = :recordIdEnterprise" select works correctly and extracts data. 
I use mySql 5.5 with EclipseLink 2.5.1 
Here examples of my classes:

```
@Entity (name = "EnterpriseEventLog")
@Table (name = "ENTERPRISE_EVENT_LOG")
public class EnterpriseEventLogEntity {

  @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn (name = "RECORD_ID_ENTERPRISE", updatable = false)
  private EnterpriseEntity enterprise;

  @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn (name = "RECORD_ID_GROUP", updatable = false)
  private GroupEntity group;
}


@Entity (name = "Enterprise")
@Table (name = "ENTERPRISE")
public class EnterpriseEntity extends EntityBase {

  @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "enterprise", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<EnterpriseEventLogEntity> eventLog = new ArrayList<> ();
}


@Entity (name = "Group")
@Table (name = "VGROUP")
public class GroupEntity extends EntityBase {

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn (name = "RECORD_ID_ENTERPRISE", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private EnterpriseEntity enterprise;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<EnterpriseEventLogEntity> eventLog = new ArrayList<>();
}


@MappedSuperclass
public class EntityBase {

  @Id
  @NotNull    
  @Column (name = "RECORD_ID", nullable = false)
  private Long recordId;
}
```

Comment: The entities that you expect the query to select have a null group, right? Hint: entity.group is an **inner** join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) said in his comment, problem is that entity.group is an inner join.
So correct query is:

```
SELECT entity
FROM EnterpriseEventLog entity LEFT JOIN entity.group group LEFT JOIN entity.enterprise enterprise
WHERE enterprise.recordId = :recordIdEnterprise     
OR  group.enterprise.recordId = :recordIdEnterprise
```

More info here: [EclipseLink User Guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#JOIN)